# primefaces use commandlink to hide one dialog and show another

Tags: primefaces

I would like to use a commandlink or something to hide the currently shown dialog and show another dialog.  Anyone have a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call the `hide()` and `show()` methods from p:commandLink.

<`p:commandLink value="open-close" onclick="dlg1.hide();dlg2.show();" />`

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf